# Method for finding strictly greater-than-zero solution for Python's Scipy Linear Programing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

[Scipy NNLS](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html#scipy.optimize.nnls) perform this:

```
Solve argmin_x || Ax - b ||_2 for x>=0.
```

What's the alternative way to do it if I seek
strictly non-zero solution (i.e. `x > 0`) ?

Here is my LP code using Scipy's NNLS:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
from scipy.optimize import nnls

def by_nnls(A=None, B=None):
    """ Linear programming by NNLS """
    #print "NOF row = ", A.shape[0]
    A = np.nan_to_num(A)
    B = np.nan_to_num(B)

    x, rnorm = nnls(A,B)
    x = x / x.sum()
    # print repr(x)
    return x

B1 = array([  22.133,  197.087,   84.344,    1.466,    3.974,    0.435,
          8.291,   45.059,    5.755,    0.519,    0.   ,   30.272,
         24.92 ,   10.095])
A1 = array([[   46.35,    80.58,    48.8 ,    80.31,   489.01,    40.98,
           29.98,    44.3 ,  5882.96],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [ 2540.73,    49.53,    26.78,    30.49,    48.51,    20.88,
           19.92,    21.05,    19.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   30.95,  1482.24,   100.48,    35.98,    35.1 ,    38.65,
           31.57,    87.38,    33.39],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   15.99,   223.27,   655.79,  1978.2 ,    18.21,    20.51,
           19.  ,    16.19,    15.91],
       [   16.49,    20.56,    19.08,    18.65,  4568.97,    20.7 ,
           17.4 ,    17.62,    25.51],
       [   33.84,    26.58,    18.69,    40.88,    19.17,  5247.84,
           29.39,    25.55,    18.9 ],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   42.66,    83.59,    99.58,    52.11,    46.84,    64.93,
           43.8 ,  7610.12,    47.13],
       [   41.63,   204.32,  4170.37,    86.95,    49.92,    87.15,
           51.88,    45.38,    42.89],
       [   81.34,    60.16,   357.92,    43.48,    36.92,    39.13,
         1772.07,    68.43,    38.07]])
```

The usage:

```
In [9]: by_nnls(A=A1,B=B1)
Out[9]:
array([ 0.70089761,  0.        ,  0.06481495,  0.14325696,  0.01218972,
        0.        ,  0.02125942,  0.01906576,  0.03851557]
```

Note the zero solution above.

Comment: Why do you want the coefficients to be strictly greater than zero? If you tried to impose such a constraint then they will likely just be pushed towards arbitrarily small positive numbers. Is there any meaningful difference between a value of 0 and, say, 2⁻¹⁰²² (which is the smallest useable non-zero value of a 64bit float)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should question if you *really* want `x > 0` instead of `x >= 0`. Usually the latter constraint serves to sparsify the result, and zeros in x are desirable. Apart from that, the constraints are practically equivalent.

If you constrain x to be strictly greater than zero, the 0s will simply become very very small positive numbers. If the soulution could be improved by larger values, you would get these values with the original constraint too.

Let's demonstrate this by defining the following optimization: Solve `argmin_x || Ax - b ||_2 for x>=eps`. While `eps > 0` this also satisfies `x > 0`. Looking at the resulting `x` for different `eps`, we get:

[image: result]

What you see is that for mall `eps` there is hardly any difference in the objective function and `x[1]` (one of the 0s in the original solution) gets closer and closer to 0.
Thus, the infinitesimal step from `x>0` to `x>=0` hardly changes anything in the solution. For practical purposes they are totally similar. However, `x>=0` has the advantage that you get actual 0s rather than 1.234e-20, which helps in sparsifying the solution.

Here is the code for above plot:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_cobyla
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def by_minimize(A, B, eps=1e-6):
    A = np.nan_to_num(A)
    B = np.nan_to_num(B)
    def objective(x, A=A, B=B):
        return np.sum((np.dot(A, x) - B)**2)
    x0 = np.zeros(A.shape[1])
    x = fmin_cobyla(objective, x0, lambda x: x-eps)
    return x / np.sum(x), objective(x)

results = []
obj = []
e = []
for eps in np.logspace(-1, -6, 100):
    x, o = by_minimize(A=A1, B=B1, eps=eps)
    e.append(eps)
    results.append(x[1])
    obj.append(o)

h1 = plt.semilogx(e, results, 'b')
plt.ylabel('x[1]', color='b')
plt.xlabel('eps')
plt.twinx()
h2 = plt.semilogx(e, obj, 'r')
plt.ylabel('objective', color='r')
plt.yticks([])
```

P.S. I have tried to implement the `x > 0` constraint in my code with `lambda x: [1 if i>0 else -1 for i in x]`, but it fails to converge.

Answer (score 4):

If you are *really* sure you want strictly positive solutions, you can use [lsq_linear](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html) which is available in the most recent scipy version. It allows a bit more control over the bounds than `nnls`.

```
In [37]: from scipy.optimize import lsq_linear

In [38]: lsq_linear(A1, B1, bounds=(0.001, np.inf))
Out[38]: 
 active_mask: array([ 0, -1,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0])
        cost: 3784.3150152135881
         fun: array([ -0.06189388, -56.45892624,  56.28407376,   2.97647016,
         0.46847016,   4.00747016,  18.24947887, -18.51852113,
         0.19599207,   7.32663679,  15.0829264 , -15.1890736 ,
        -0.14570891,  -0.24341795])
     message: 'The first-order optimality measure is less than `tol`.'
         nit: 17
  optimality: 5.4491449547056092e-11
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([ 0.05506904,  0.001     ,  0.00501077,  0.01112669,  0.001     ,
        0.001     ,  0.00154812,  0.00147833,  0.00300156])
```